# Symfony 2 basic GET form generated URL

Tags: forms, url, symfony, get, formbuilder

I have been trying to create an extremely basic symfony form (used for search functionality) with only one input. It uses GET method on submit. It seems to work as expected, however it generates an extremely ugly and unnecessarily long URL. I have been trying to 'clean' the URL up for a quite a while now, I was wondering if someone ran into the same problem and knows how to fix it?

Form

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($search)
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->add('q', 'text')
            ->add('search', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
```

On submit the form generates the following URL:

```
search?form[q]=red+apple&form[search]=&form[_token]=bb342d7ef928e984713d8cf3eda9a63440f973f2
```

Desired URL:

```
search?q=red+apple
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17):

To create your desired URL, you will have to set the form name by using `createNamedBuilder` which you'll just leave blank `''`.
To remove `_token` you need to set `csrf_protection` to false. Please look into csrf protection to make sure you know what could happen if it is turned off.

Changing your code to the following should give you the results you want.

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('', 'form', $search, array(
            'csrf_protection' => false,
         ))->setMethod('GET')
           ->add('q', 'text')
           ->add('search', 'submit')
           ->getForm();
```

This should produce a URL like:

```
search?q=red+apple&search=
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get rid of `&search=`, one way would be to change `search` from `submit` to `button`.

```
->add('search', 'button')
```

This will require javascript to submit your form.
Here is simple example in jquery:

```
//This assumes one form and one button
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

This will produce a URL like:

```
search?q=red+apple
```

To access GET vars you put something like this in your controller:

```
public function yourSearchAction(Request $request)
{
    // your code ...

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $getVars = $form->getData();

        $q = $getVars['q'];
        $page = $getVars['page'];
        $billing = $em

        //Do something

    }

    return //your code

}
```

Just to clarify if you are adding `page` to your URL you will need to add it to your form:

```
->add('page', 'text')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked quite well. Is there any way to remove the `&search=` from the URL?

Comment: Also if I create a `href` like `search?q=red+apple&search=&page=2`, how would I access the `page` GET var in the controller? I appreciate the help.

Comment: I have edited the post to answer these two questions.

Comment: To get rid of `&search=` you can also create your form without the `->add('search', 'submit')` and add your own submit-button `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Find</button>`

Answer (score 3):

Old question but, for people who want to know, this does the job too (Symfony 2.8) :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/SearchType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->add('q', TextType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class))
        ;
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix(){
        return '';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your controller :

```
<?php
//...
use AppBundle\Form\SearchType;
//...
public function yourSearchAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $q = $form->get('q')->getData();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good one! The only thing needed from this answer, is to override `public function getBlockPrefix()` to return empty string