# Symfony Forms - handling several request methods

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In our legacy project, there is an API where user can submit data via both GET and POST requests. Is it possible somehow to handle both GET and POST requests by one form?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What error did you get ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different methods in your controller and then through the routing, determine how to handle the GET or POST request. Note below both routes are the same but we restrict the request method. The names of the routes must be different

```
/**
 * This method accepts on GET or PUT
 * @Route("/view/{id}", name="blueprint_view")
 * @Method({"GET", "PUT"})
 */
 public function viewAction(Request $request, $id)
 {
    ....
 }


 /**
 * The method accepts POST
 *
 * @Route("/view/{id}", name="blueprint_post_view")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
 public function viewPostAction(Request $request, $id)
 {
    ....
 }
```

Now in your methods you can know what to expect and how to parse out the request params.

Comment: I don't think it would work - symfony form has option "method" that uses to determine which method it uses, that's why handleRequest will not hadle both GET and POST.

Comment: It can handle both. Check the documentation. Why else would the form be allowed to set the method if Symfony didnt allow GET to be handled?

Comment: To help clarify, see the answer to another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308945/symfony-2-basic-get-form-generated-url